# Template to register games of GO. Igo package not working in overleaf

Tags: packages, overleaf

I write my documents in Overleaf and I'm trying to use the [igo package](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/fonts/igo/igo.pdf).

But overleaf says

```
LaTeX Error: File `igo.sty' not found.
l.3 \begin
      {document}^^M
```

Even if I create the corresponding `igo.sty` file. Please help me

I only want a template that uses some Go package to register some games.

Comment: Have you uploaded igo.sty from here [style file] (https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/igo) to your Overleaf project folder?

Comment: Indeed `igo` is not included in TeX Live and therefore not on Overleaf...

Comment: @MiguelRomán perhaps you can confirm that this was the Problem and the query is answered (for future refernce)?

Comment: @LianTzeLim DO you want to add an answer here?

Answer (score 5):

(Disclaimer: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.)

`igo` isn't included in TeX Live, and therefore not available by default on Overleaf. An alternative is to use the `psgo` package instead (which *is* in TeX Live), e.g. (from the [documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/psgo))

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{psgo}

\begin{document}
\begin{psgoboard}[9]
\move*{c}{3}
\move*{g}{7}
\pass*
\move*{f}{1}
\move*{a}{9}
\move{f}{6}  % new \move commands
\move{e}{6}
\pass
\move{c}{5}
\end{psgoboard}
\end{document}
```

Here's an example project on Overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/read/fzyvmvdxqsvr. Use the `LaTeX dvipdf` or `XeLaTeX` engine on Overleaf; you can change the "LaTeX engine" setting in your own project after clicking on the gear icon above the preview panel.